# Cleaning memory in python

Tags: python, linux, shell, out-of-memory

So I have some script and I have trouble with memory.

How to 'clean memory' in python script or do something like that?

In one loop I don't have any troubles but let's say in 2000 loop execution I have a bug.

```
> Out of memory: Kill process 9158 (python) score 798 or sacrifice child
> Killed process 9158 (python) total-vm:2239864kB, anon-rss:1768792kB,
> file-rss:0kB
```

or on small vps

```
> [3533150.960369] Out of memory in UB 416: OOM killed process 17106
> (python) score 0 vm:311848kB, rss:122612kB, swap:107260k
```

Comment: profile your code https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/muppy.html,https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler

Answer (score 2):

usually python takes care of the memory pretty well. I would guess you have some memory leak in your script (e.g. global varables containing more and more data every loop iteration)

It is a good idea to use small functions and have local variables there. At the exit of the function all memory allocated for local variables is automatically released.

I don't know details of your script so that's difficult to suggest anything meaningful